# AngularJS - How do I filter an array of 'deep' objects given an array of values to filter by?

Tags: angularjs, filter

I am trying to filter my data which I am getting from a HTTP GET endpoint by an array of values

`filters = ['Full Time', 'LinkedIn', ...]`

The general structure of the response I am getting back is an array of objects where each object can look like this:

```
 {
    "preferences": {
      "jobType": {
        "type": "Full Time"
      }
    },
    "profile": {
      "additionalinfo": {
        "organization": [
          {
            "name": "Google"
          },
          {
             "name": "LinkedIn"
          }
        ],
        "university": [
           {
            "name": "UC Berkeley",
            "degrees": [ {"name": "Computer Engineering"}]
           }
      }
    }
  }
```

So if I filter by ["Google", "Full Time"], the above object should be included.

Is there a built in filter to handle this?

I am having trouble writing the custom filter to handle such a heavily nested object.

Any ideas on how to implement this?

Comment: maybe a loop over the elements and use a combination of JSON.stringify and string.indexOf?

Comment: Use the built-in filter filter twice? E.g., `x | filter : "Google" | filter : "Full Time" `

Comment: @user113215 this works except, I want the filter to be dynamic. How would you implement it such that it works not just for 2 parameters, but n parameters in the form of an array: ["Google", "LinkedIn", "Full Time", ...]?

Comment: @c0de You could write your own filter that calls `x = $filter('filter')(x, query)` in a loop, once for each `query` parameter in your array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use built in `filter` like this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/py79hovc/)

```js
var myApp = angular.module("myApp", []);

myApp.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{
    "preferences": {
      "jobType": {
        "type": "Full Time"
      }
    },
    "profile": {
      "additionalinfo": {
        "organization": [{
          "name": "Google"
        }, {
          "name": "LinkedIn"
        }],
        "university": [{
          "name": "UC Berkeley",
          "degrees": [{
            "name": "Computer Engineering"
          }]
        }]
      }
    }
  }, {
    "preferences": {
      "jobType": {
        "type": "Remote"
      }
    },
    "profile": {
      "additionalinfo": {
        "organization": [{
          "name": "Yandex"
        }, {
          "name": "LinkedIn"
        }],
        "university": [{
          "name": "UC Berkeley",
          "degrees": [{
            "name": "Computer Engineering"
          }]
        }]
      }
    }
  }];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <h3>Jobs</h3> 
  <input ng-model="filterModelJobType" placeholder="filter jobType">
  <input ng-model="filterModelJob" placeholder="filter job">
  <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="x in data|filter:{profile: {additionalinfo:{organization:{name:filterModelJob}}},preferences: {jobType:{type:filterModelJobType}}}">
        <td>{{ $index + 1 | number }}</td>
        <td class="text-center">{{ x.preferences.jobType.type }}</td>
        <td class="text-left">
          <div ng-repeat="org in x.profile.additionalinfo.organization">
            <hr> {{org.name}}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: this works, but I am using input type=checkbox and not just a text field. from your example, it looks like I have to separate the filters by their filter types and create 3 separate arrays. Is there a way to do this with only one array? for example, if I give you filter array =  ["UC Berkeley", "LinkedIn", "Full Time"]

Comment: You may  try pass into `filter` as object, not array. See updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Stepan_Kasyanenko/py79hovc/).

Comment: I think you would have been easier to write your own `filter`. There you can `filter` what you need and with the parameters that should be.

Answer (score 0):

In the latest version of [AngularJS](https://code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js)

If there is nested object then

```
var foo = $filter('filter')($scope.welcome, {
  additionalinfo: { name: 'google' }
});
```

Reference: [GitHub issue](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/b4eed8ad94ce9719540462c1ee969dfd3c6b2355)